# why dont i have universal tween engine when setting up LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, game-engine, tween

Following a tutorial on setting up A LibGDX project and the tutorial says that in the third party section there should be a Universal Tween Engine. Mines not showing up, is there a way for it to show up? What do i have to download?

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine

Answer (score 3):

The Gdx-setup-new-ui-jar does not come with TweenEngine library.
There is another way of adding Universal TweenEngine. Since you are using Gradle now, so it is very easy.

just download the TweenEngine from here https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/downloads/list and paste it in your core/libs android/libs and ios/libs folders.

in build.gradle add this line at the end of dependencies of core, android and ios.

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

like this:

```
    project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

     dependencies {
      compile project(":core")
      compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
      natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
      natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
     }
    }
```

then just clean/build your project and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

LibGdx uses gradle for dependency management.
You can inject dependency from repository.

```
repositories {
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

add these lines in your core module of root build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4'
compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4:sources'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me changing:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

to:

`compile fileTree(dir: '../libs/tween-engine-api-6.3.3 2', include: '*.jar')`

did the trick. (Obviously your file name may be different (no `2` on the end for example))